# How to group breakpoints in IntelliJ ultimate based on class/package automatically?

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea, breakpoints

In Eclipse we have the feature where we can group breakpoints automatically based on projects and class files. But in IntelliJ the group breakpoints option asks for manual grouping.
Is there a way by using some extension or something through with we can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The is an issue in 2020.2 version that grouping by package/class/file is not available. But in 2020.3 version it has been fixed. And you can use it in Breakpoints dialog:

[image]